# How to add EditText elements in Android on the same activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a `DetailsActivity` which has a `TextView` and `TimeEditText` for **Date**. User can add a date in that. There is a `Button` called `Add Detail`

I want that when a user enters a date like d-m-yy (future) then below this `TimeEditText` element, the activity should show a no. of `WeekEditText` as

Week1: `WeekEditText1` *(To add details for 1st week)*

Week2: `WeekEditText2` *(To add details for 2nd week)* and so on.

The total no. of week is `(AddedDate - CurrentDate)/7`

One of way of doing is calling another new activity on clicking `Add Detail` button and then showing all *EditTexts* on next activity while passsing `AddedDate` etc through Intent.

But is it possible to show `EditText` on same page below `TimeEditText` after user enters a date?

Comment: What's a TimeEditText?

Comment: TimeEditText is the TextEdit View for entering date from the user. And based on the entered date in TimeEditText i want to show all the other EditTextViews

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `Button` that when clicked adds the number of `EditText`s you need

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // do whatever else you need here
    int numWeeks =(AddedDate - CurrentDate)/7;
    for (i=1; i<=numWeeks;i++)
    {
         EditText et = new EditText(YourActivity.this);
         // add whatever here
    }
}
```

You can add whatever kind of `Layout` you want before creating the `EditText` then add each one to that `Layout`. Something like that ought to work for you

Comment: But i don't want a button click. It should happen as soon as user finishes adding the date.//// Also how can i be sure about no. of invisible EdiText as user can add any long date.

Comment: Then I guess I'm confused on what exactly you want. You want some user action for the `EditText` to show. What if they mess up the date...you want them to be able to correct it before moving on.

Comment: So you have the total # of `EditText` you need, use a `for loop` to dynamically create them and do what you need with each in the `loop`. But I still think you need a `Button` or some action in case the user makes a mistake because I know its rare but does happen ;)

Comment: I tried 'OnFocusChange' event of 'DateEditText' to run the loop instead of any button click. But if i insert above loop in its code it gives error: "The constructor EditText() is undefined" how should i proceed?

Comment: ^^^ okay resolved above one through using EditText(Activity.this). Silly error

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wrote that kind of fast and it was late so I forgot to put that in there. I edited my answer to reflect that. I was going to suggest `OnFocusChange()` but I still think its a good idea to have some user acknowledgement to proceed but maybe I don't exactly understand the context. I'm glad you got it working. Please feel free to accept if this answer helped so others can find it easier

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically inflate a layout or layout element such as and Edit Text.
For Example,

```
if(TimeEditText.getText != null)
 EditText et = new EditText();
```